# How to add new column to existing csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, append

For instance, **x** is my data and **r** is supposed to be new data to be added.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]], np.int32)
np.savetxt("test.csv", x, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')

r = [1,2,3]
```

how could I add it to that **"test.csv"**

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a new column by using the [insert function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) in numpy like so

```
np.insert(x, 3, [r], axis=1)
```

Comment: `np.insert` does not operate in place.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just about adding a column to an existing 2d array. Writing it to a csv file is just a further step and isn't affected by this addition.

```
In [96]: x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
    ...:               [4, 5, 6],
    ...:               [7, 8, 9]], np.int32)
In [97]: r = [1,2,3]
```

There are a number of functions that can add a column to an array, but they all end up using `concatenate`.  And knowing how to use `concatenate` directly is a good thing to know.  The key is matching the number of dimensions.

```
In [98]: x1 = np.concatenate((x, np.array(r)[:,None]), axis=1)
In [99]: x1
Out[99]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 2],
       [7, 8, 9, 3]])
```

`vstack` takes care of turning `r` into this column array.  `insert` is more general, allowing you to add values within the existing (not just at the end).  But like `concatenate` (and all the stacks) it does not operate in-place.

Comment: What if a user doesn't want to change the arrays?